# How to wait for Retrofit async operation to complete in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await

I am new to Kotlin, coming from C# it I am quite used to `async\await`

How do I wait for `tvClient` to get the response before returning the list of channels?

```
override fun getChannels(): MutableList<Channel> {
        disposable = tvClient.getChannels()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        {Log.d("***", it.toString())},
                        {Log.d("***",it.toString())}
                )


    TODO("wait for tvClient to return results")

    return mChannels;
}
```

I tried using coroutines but no luck

What is the best way to wait for async operation to complete in Kotlin?

Comment: the best way to do that would be to use coroutines, but you're not using that. This is not possible with Rx. Instead you have to return tv.getChannels() and subscribe to it in the method that calls this method

Comment: Starting with coroutines isn't going to be a picnic, either, they don't remove the fact that the things have gone async, in effect creating concurrency on the GUI thread. You'll also have to `launch` a coroutine and your whole call chain leading into `getChannels()` will have to consists of `suspend fun`s.

Answer (score 1):

You're using *RxJava* and thus you should implement it in a reactive way.

If you're app is not build for it yet, you can get the value blocking. Assuming `getChannels()` returns a single you could just call `blockingGet()` instead of `subscribe()`.

But be aware that **this blocks** the thread the outer `getChannels()` is called from.

Using coroutines might be better for you. It's a little nearer to what you know from *C#* and with the [*retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter) you can integrate directly with *Retrofit*.

Answer (score 0):

you can check a functional implementation of kotlin v1.3 retrofit + stable coroutines using DSL here https://github.com/eriknyk/networkcall-sample/commits/master

DSL template:

```
fun <RESPONSE: DataResponse<*>, DATA: Any> networkCall(block: CallHandler<RESPONSE, DATA>.() -> Unit): MutableLiveData<Resource<DATA>>
    = CallHandler<RESPONSE, DATA>().apply(block).makeCall()

    interface DataResponse<T> {
    fun retrieveData(): T
}
```

and using it:

```
fun getRepos(query: String) = networkCall<ResposResponse, List<Repo>> {
    client = githubService.getRepos(query)
}
```

Hope it helps.